# How to get better results when using the TensorFlow object detection API for a custom trained model to recognize hand poses?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection

in my project I need to train a object detection model which is able to recognize hands in different poses in real-time from a rgb webcam.
Thus, I'm using the TensorFlow object detection API.
What I did so far is training the model based on the ssd_inception_v2 architecture with the ssd_inception_v2_coco model as finetune-checkpoint.
I want to detect 10 different classes of hand poses. Each class has 300 images which are augmented. In total there are 2400 images in for training and 600 for evaluation. The labeling was done with LabelImg.

The Problem is that the model isn't able to detect the different classes properly. Even if it still wasn't good I got much better results by training with the same images, but only with like 3 different classes. It seems like the problem is the SSD architecture. I've read several times that SSD networks are not good in detecting small objects.

Finally, my questions are the following:

- Could I receive better results by using a faster_rcnn_inception architecture for this use case?
- Has anyone some advice how to optimize the model?
- Do I need more images?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Faster_rcnn_inception might be good for this, also why not Try YOLO?

Comment: I want to load the model in the app which needs to be able to detect the hand poses. For this I'm using OpenCV, which is not able to load YOLO models. Is it worth it to check this out?

Comment: If by app you are referring to a Mobile APP, then YOLO does work in Android. You could use the Annotated data made for ssd architecture to YOLO too

Comment: I looked it up, OpenCV is also able to load Darknet models like YOLO. So there would be no problem with this. Can you tell me why YOLO is better for this purpose?